# Bzip2 block header: 1AY&SY

Tags: block, archive, bzip2

This is the question about bzip2 [archive format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2#File_format). Any Bzip2 archive consists of file header, one or more blocks and tail structure. All blocks should start with "1AY&SY", 6 bytes of BCD-encoded digits of the Pi number, 0x314159265359. According to [the source of bzip2](http://web.archive.org/web/20060320104423/http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/lin/cs380c/bzip2.c):

```
/*--
  A 6-byte block header, the value chosen arbitrarily
  as 0x314159265359 :-).  A 32 bit value does not really
  give a strong enough guarantee that the value will not
  appear by chance in the compressed datastream.  Worst-case
  probability of this event, for a 900k block, is about
  2.0e-3 for 32 bits, 1.0e-5 for 40 bits and 4.0e-8 for 48 bits.
  For a compressed file of size 100Gb -- about 100000 blocks --
  only a 48-bit marker will do.  NB: normal compression/
  decompression do *not* rely on these statistical properties.
  They are only important when trying to recover blocks from
  damaged files.
--*/
```

The question is: Is it true, that all bzip2 archives will have blocks with start aligned to byte boundary?  I mean all archives created by reference implementation of bzip2, the bzip2-1.0.5+ utility.

I think that bzip2 may parse the stream not as byte stream but as bit stream (the block itself is encoded by huffman, which is not byte-aligned by design).

So, in other words: If `grep -c 1AY&SY` greater (huffman may generate 1AY&SY inside block) or equal to count of bzip2 blocks in the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BZIP2 looks at a bit stream.

From http://blastedbio.blogspot.com/2011/11/random-access-to-bzip2.html:

> Anyway, the important bits are that a BZIP2 file contains one or more
>   "streams", which are byte aligned, each containing one (zero?) or more
>   "blocks", which are not byte aligned, followed by an end of stream
>   marker (the six bytes 0x177245385090 which is the square root of pi as
>   a binary coded decimal (BCD), a four byte checksum, and empty bits for
>   byte alignment).

The bzip2 [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2) article also alludes to bit-block alignment (see the File Format section), which seems to be inline from what I remember from school (had to implement the algorithm...).

Comment: Was it some cruel kind of school?

Comment: Not that cruel, no :) It was a course on Data Compression offered by a visiting professor. This guy: http://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~nigelh/

Comment: So, I can do search for 0x314159265359 and all variants of shifted constant to find blocks?

Comment: That seems to make intuitive sense. Not sure about implementation considerations though. You may want to take a peek at this project: https://bitbucket.org/james_taylor/seek-bzip2

Comment: And we can see that this project is actually decompressing without calculating CRC: https://bitbucket.org/james_taylor/seek-bzip2/src/68ba278025b5d6e093621492f40c24f77891beb4/bzip-table.c?at=seek-bzip2 ("This does not completely uncompress the data, so does not do CRC checks, * (gaining 60% or so speedup)"), they selected the slow way. I still want to throw the seek-bzip2 away, like it was 3 years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3701268/196561

Comment: seek-bzip does the decompression calculations without creating a decompressed output stream. It does this to work out which byte offset in the uncompressed stream matches each marked bit offset in the compressed stream.